# RabbitMQ Exception 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

Tags: .net, .net-core, rabbitmq, console-application, messaging

I followed a tutorial on RabbitMQ and got stuck at an exception that occurs when creating the connection. The whole method is shown below:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var factory = new ConnectionFactory { Uri = new Uri("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:15672/") };
        using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        using var channel = connection.CreateModel();
        channel.QueueDeclare("demo-queue",
            durable: true,
            exclusive: false,
            autoDelete: false,
            arguments: null);

        var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
        consumer.Received += (sender, e) =>
        {
            var body = e.Body.ToArray();
            var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        };
        channel.BasicConsume("demo-queue", true, consumer);
    }
}
```

On this line: `using var connection = factory.CreateConnection();` I am getting this:

> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

And three inner exceptions:

> ExtendedSocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. 127.0.0.1:15672

> ConnectFailureException: Connection failed

> AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Connection failed)

What is the cause of this exception? Is the Uri wrong or not set up correctly beforehand? RabbitMQ seems to be working well as I could log into http://localhost:15672/ and it's up and running.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: I put 5672 as the port in the Uri and the result is the same.

Comment: ampq and http protocols are not the same
. 5672 - try this port if default config is set

Comment: Thanks @Igor. Unfortunately, the result is still the same.

Comment: I had the same problem and I fixed it by reinstalling RabbitMQ.

Comment: @Questieme Hi, did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After turning the firewall off, it started working.

Comment: Did you just turn off the whole FW, or did you open some port(s)?